# local Swf bridge to remote Swf to go around flash sandbox

Tags: flash, actionscript, sandbox

Goal: to make possible to make requests from flash running on local protocol (widget://, file://, chrome-extension://) without any special permissions on www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html

Supposed solution: proxy swf file loaded in page with widget:// or file:// or chrome-extension:// protocol which loads into itself swf file located on http server. local swf bridge conects its own external interface to http swf file external interface.

This solution used in youtube movies, so you can embed any youtube movie into local page and it will be shown  and played fine;

At the end we can get working soundmanager2 www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/ opened localy (file:// protocol), which can load and play music and video from internet. I need proxy for this version http://github.com/scottschiller/SoundManager2/tree/V2.95b.20100323/src;

Some relative
help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7e5c.html
[How do I call a Flex SWF from a remote domain using Flash (AS3)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350/how-do-i-call-a-flex-swf-from-a-remote-domain-using-flash-as3)

I need this to play music in opera extension (using widget:// protocol) for my project http://seesu.me/ to let users play music without setting up special permissions

Comment: How can possible looks code of swf sources? I'm javasript, but not actionscript developer

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will get you on track.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000349.html